# How do I broadcast desktop internet using wireless router

Tags: router, wireless-router, internet-sharing

I need to broadcast desktop internet connection using [Linksys E900 router](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/routers/E900). When I put desktop ethernet cable into `internet port` of router, router is not detected by the system.

However, I have been able to connect multiple computer when using peer to peer connection using other ports.

Comment: The Internet port on the router is for providing Internet to the router, not to a client connected to the router. Have you considered reading the manual for your device?

Comment: @moses My understanding is `providing internet to router means, providing connectivity to a server` which already has access to internet. Correct me if I am wrong?